# Unable to select dynamically generated form elements (ajax)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, firefox, dynamic

I have a main.php page

the following code is hardcoded in main form

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
```

the following is the code generated dynamically using AJAX

```
<input type="checkbox" value="test" name="test[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="test1" name="test[]"/>

<input type="submit" value="go">
```

ideally speaking on clicking the go button the page should submit to test.php page with the post value of the check elements
but now i find no action is taken by the browser. Also i find no error message in error console.
this used to work upto firefox 3.5 and IE 8. However in Firefox 3.6 the dynamically generated form elements are not recognized at all 
Is there a mistake in the code and is a there a work around

Comment: Did you close your `<form>` tag?

Comment: You have square brackets (special symbols) in the name of the generated inputs. Also no id value.

Comment: @jdk There's nothing wrong with both. In fact, ruby on rails constantly generates names with square brackets and nobody yet complained.

Comment: You are expecting the values to come through as an array under $_POST['test'] right?  Also (correct me if I'm wrong) but if you don't check the box, no value will be submitted for that particular field.  

I see no issue with this code (assuming you close your form) and no indication that its functionality would be browser dependent.  Perhaps if you post your Javascript we'd have some insight into the possible source of the browser differences.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the dynamic content does not replace the `form` .. but gets appended to it (or replaces the contents and not the actual `form` tag..)